# Ninject Providers -> Get another dependency inside the provider

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm wondering what the best practices is here.
I need to construct a DbContext for my multi tenanted application, so I have made a Dependency provider like this:

```
public class TenantContextFactoryProvider : Provider<DbContext>
{
    protected override DbContext CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        var tenant = // How to get the tenant through ninject??
        return new DbContext(tenant.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

I need ninject to resolve the tenant dependency, but I'm not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While service locator certainly works, constructor injection is another choice.

```
public class TenantContextFactoryProvider : Provider<DbContext>
{
    ITenant tenant; 
    public TenantContextFactoryProvider(ITenant tenant)
    {
         this.tenant = tenant;
    }

    protected override DbContext CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        return new DbContext(tenant.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could do that, I wrongly assumed that when I was inside the initiation of ninject, I couldn't access these kinds of features.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit embarassing, but I guess if it can happen to me, it can happen to someone else as well.

I forgot to include `using Ninject`, which is why the extension method `context.Kernel.Get` wasn't showing up, in IntelliSense.

So my code ended up looking like this:

```
using Ninject;
public class TenantContextFactoryProvider : Provider<DbContext>
{
    protected override DbContext CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        var tenant = context.Kernel.Get<ITenant>();
        return new DbContext(tenant.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Comment: so the answer is to use service locator for the provider dependency?

Comment: Yes, the answer to my problem is I forgot to include Ninject in the .cs file. Nothing special :) Just a 'brain-fart'.

Comment: i think a better approach might be using constructor injection rather than service locator.

Comment: @liang I think you are missing the point here. This is Ninject part of the code. This is a helper for Ninject to create the right objects for constructor injection. I am setting up Ninject with this code.

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether it's "Ninject part of the code", as long as the dependency is managed by Ninject.

Comment: If you have another solution, post it as an answer.