# Ninject Providers: what is the correct way to resolve dependencies

Tags: c#, ninject

In my application I can register different datasources by name. These data-sources each have a few `string` properties required, along with a set of other dependencies, but are otherwise the same, so take a few different standard implementations.

To construct instances of each datasource when requested, I create a binding to an instance of a `Provider<T>` which is initialized with the information required to access that data-source. The provider looks something like the below:

```
public class StandardListProvider<T> : Provider<IListExecutor<T>>
    where T : new()
{
    public string Name       { get; set; }
    public string ListMethod { get; set; }

    public StandardListProvider(string name, string listMethod)
    {
        Name       = name;
        ListMethod = listMethod;
    }

    protected override IListExecutor<T> CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        var connector = (IInternalConnector)context.Kernel.GetService(typeof(IInternalConnector));
        return new StandardListExecutor<T>(connector, Name)
        {
            ListMethodName = ListMethod
        };
    }
}
```

The problem is with resolving dependencies of the `StandardListExecutor<T>` like `IInternalConnector`. Obviously I can construct them manually, or request them from `context.Kernel` as I am in my example (and suggested by [Ninject Providers -> Get another dependency inside the provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001121/ninject-providers-get-another-dependency-inside-the-provider)), but this results in a request with no Target information, which is not ideal if we want to perform contextual bindings for the dependencies of `StandardListExecutor`.

I've tried playing with `context.Request.CreateChild(...)`, but this appears to require reflection on every activation to create a `ParameterTarget`. There doesn't appear to be much information about this in the Ninject docs either.

My question is: What is the correct way to resolve/request dependencies, or other services like this from within the activation process of an existing binding?

**Edit**

The requests themselves are made via the Ninject.Mvc hookups into the System.Web.Mvc controller activation process.

Comment: What's missing from your question is how the provided objects are actually "requested". Hence I don't really see the need for a provider here. Why don't you just create a binding instead? You can add constructor arguments to the binding. Better practice might be to create a `FooParameters` or `FooSettings` type for each executor though.

Comment: Hi @BatteryBackupUnit - the actual requests are made via the Ninject.Mvc hookups into the controller activation process. The idea of creating a binding to handle all this honestly hadn't occurred to me, neither had creating a settings object for each different kind of executor. I really wanted to get as much activation logic as possible **out** of the binding as the bindings themselves are created by an `IMissingBindingResolver`. In any case the meat of my question is about how best to create custom `Provider`s, as this question has come up for me on a few different projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the extension [Ninject.Extensions.ContextPreservation](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.ContextPreservation/). Specifically the extension method `IContext.ContextPreservingGet(...)`:

```
var connector = context.ContextPreservingGet<IInternalConnector>();
```

However, personally I think that creating specific settings types is the better choice - because it's the simpler idea.